# R Shiny update plots daily from Google Drive

Tags: r, shiny

So Ive seen quite some posts about updating a R Shiny app periodically and have read about it. But one thing I still dont understand whats 'better'

So my workflow is that I run a daily R script to clean up data. Moreover plots are already created via various functions, which can take a while (like 100's of ms - which you dont want in your Shiny app right cause users do experience this?) These plots are saved as .RData to Google Drive.

The next step is to have these plots updated in the R Shiny app daily where it fetches the .RData files from connecting to Google Drive.

So my question: does this fetching of the .RData needs to takes place in the global file or at the server side? Also in terms of loading speed of the users.

Its a bit difficult to have an example code which connects to Google Drive but here is a shot (FYI it doesnt work with connecting to GD, but just to see the workflow):

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(googledrive)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Load Plotly Plot from Google Drive"),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("loaded_plot")
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  MyPlot <- observe({   
    invalidateLater(86400000, session) 
    
    #auth Google Drive
    drive_auth()
    
    #download plot from Google Drive
    drive_download("plot.RData")

  })
  
  # Render the plotly plot
  output$loaded_plot <- renderPlotly({
    MyPlot
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so I got the periodically check on a Google Sheet working. the download option of the googldrive package only downloads locally which I dont want so I changed workflow. In the example it checks every 30 seconds a Google Sheet.

The only thing I wonder if I do it correctly is to update the MyPlot. Now I hvae it included in the reactivePoll...but I assume this can be more elegantly right?

```
# * Global

library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)

# Function plotly plot
plotly_scatter <- function(df, x, y) {
  
  fig <- plot_ly(df) 
  
  fig <- fig %>% 
    add_lines(type = 'scatter', mode = "lines",
              x = ~x, y = ~y)
  
  return(fig)
}

data_frame <- reactivePoll(
  intervalMillis = 30000,
  session = NULL,
  checkFunc = function() {
    #authentication
    drive_auth()
    gs4_auth(token = drive_token())
    
    #Read in Google Sheet
    gs_file<- drive_get('df')
    gs_data <<- read_sheet(gs_file)
    
    #Create plotly plot
    MyPlot <<- plotly_scatter(gs_data, x, y)
    
  }
)


# * UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Load Plotly Plot from Google Drive"),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("loaded_plot")
  )
)

# * Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
    # Render the plotly plot
    output$loaded_plot <- renderPlotly({
      MyPlot
    })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If the objects are static inside the app, then from what I understand they should be loaded in global as that is only loaded once when the app initiates whereas the server is run separately for each session (user)

Comment: Since I don't think 100-200ms is abysmal in a shiny app, you could put the plotting code in the app in a condition: if it exists in a cache, pull it and use it, otherwise create it and save it. There are several easy mechanisms for handling a cache, including the `cachem` package. While the first person might "pay a price" (of a quarter sec?), and you might have to deal with high-frequency concurrency, it may simplify your `.Rdata` questions.

Comment: Right, I have to change it anyways cause `drive_download` doesnt add the .RData file to the Shiny env but only downloads it locally...so my plan is to load a google sheet dataframe and than indeed create the plotly plots in the global env....what do you mean btw with high-frequency concurrency?